# exit() doesn't work with cx_freeze

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, cx-freeze

I have a program in which I use a tkinter button to exit the program with the `exit()` command. However, when I compile the program through `cx_freeze`, it doesn't work anymore. I also tried with `sys.exit()` but then the button doesn't work at all (with or without `cx_freeze`). Any hint would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Have you tried `name_of_application.destroy()` instead?

Comment: It works, thanks! I didn't use that at first because I thought it wouldn't stop the program but since it breaks the loop, it automatically does.

Comment: Cool; added as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For `tkinter` applications, the preferred way to exit is `name_of_application.destroy()`. Using `exit()` can give unpredictable results.